# Coordinate System unexpectedly move down

Tags: iphone, view, coordinates, coordinate-systems

[image: Coordinate System Move_Down]

In the Login View, I add this action to the loginButton.
[self presentModalViewController:tabBarViewController animated:YES];
The tabBarView is definitely the view shown in the picture.

Then the whole coordinate system weirdly move down.

Could anybody tell the potential reason?

Will really appreciate your answer.

Comment: is it happening only when u present `tabBarController`..? try with any other viewController.. let me know what happens..

Comment: yes problem occurs when i present the tabBarController. Is the present method relevant to this problem?

Comment: yes i think so.. and i think tabBarController can be used as rootViewController of window only, not any where else.. they have `UIToolBar` if you want u can replace tabBar with toolBar..